# Retriveing users from user store in wso2is-km (IDM) using SCIM user apis

Tags: scim, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is-km 5.6.0 and wso2am 2.5.0. I am using scim user api for retrieving users list from user store. 
API: https://localhost:9444/wso2/scim/Users
But I got the following issue.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint} -  Internal server error.
org.wso2.charon.core.exceptions.CharonException: Error while retrieving users from user store..
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.listUsers(SCIMUserManager.java:330)
        at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.list(UserResourceEndpoint.java:465)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserResource.getUser(UserResource.java:206)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database error occurred while listing users for a property : scimId & value : % & profile name : default
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:173)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserList(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1294)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.listUsers(SCIMUserManager.java:313)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:166)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database error occurred while listing users for a property : scimId & value : % & profile name : default
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getUserListFromProperties(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2862)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserList(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1450)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserList(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1388)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 6
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1036)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getUserListFromProperties(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2845)
        ... 75 more
```

NOTE: Here I am using mysql jdbc driver.

Comment: Hi, can you please post the exact curl you used to get the users through the SCIM API